# If a stock is in a bull market, is setting a stop limit a good way to protect myself from a crash or bear market?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

Say the stock has been increasing quickly, and is currently at $1000.  Would selling it if it reaches $900, and rebuying if it jumps back up to $1000 quickly be a decent strategy?  If I'm wrong the most I can lose is $100 + transaction fees, if I'm right I can potentially gain a much larger amount if it crashes hard enough.

Comment: What do the body of your text have to do with "*setting a stop limit a good way to protect myself from a crash or bear market*"?

Comment: Also, you've lost $100 only if you own one share of stock.

Comment: This is really up to you. That strategy may work or it may not. But keep this in mind.. you are guaranteed to be able to buy at a high price but not sell at a high price.

Comment: Problem is that a stop loss converts to a market sell when the price is triggered and in a real crash your actual sale price might be much much lower.

Answer (score 3):

The normal sequence is to set a stop-limit below the current value, and move it up in line with any increases. You lock-in the gains. 
Forget about 'buying low, selling high'. Everyone wants to do that. By definition for every winner there is a loser. You cannot time the market. Churning has costs. Buffet is a fan of buy and hold. So am I.

Comment: And don't forget wash sale rules.

Answer (score 0):

No. In order to make money, you have to buy low and sell high. You are suggesting to sell low and buy high.

Comment: Technically, it's "selling high, and buying higher".  Still a not so great idea.

Comment: @RonJohn unless the buying higher is a stop loss on a short sale.

Comment: @MD-Tech nothing in the Q about short selling.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a stock you already own or are you asking about short selling?

If you already own stock that's currently worth $1,000, then setting a stop-limit that will sell if the price falls below $900 will put a limit on your losses if it drops and carries on doing so. If it was a temporary "blip" and it picks-up again, you could then re-buy (with a bit of a loss) in the hope it carries on rising. But in either case you won't "*gain a much larger amount if it crashes hard enough.*"

If you *don't* already own the stock and you're asking about short selling (selling something you don't have at one price and buying it back later [to "repay" the ones you sold] at a hopefully lower, but possibly higher price) then that's different. If it's currently $1,000 and you decide to "short-sell" if it hits $900, then two things can happen:

- It continues to fall in price. The longer it falls, the cheaper it will be when you buy it back and repay the "loan" you short-sold. This *could* potentially gain quite a lot, up to a **maximum** just shy of $900 if it were to drop to a dollar a share.
- If the drop to $900 was a blip, and it climbs back up again, then **if** you manage to buy-back at $1,000 then you will only have lost $100. However, the price could – at least in theory – climb much higher before you are able to buy (see [the story of  how to turn $37k into a $106k loss](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/121515/how-short-sellers-account-went-negative-106k.asp)) and you could potentially end up losing an **unlimited** amount (quite easily more than the original $1,000 price).

Answer (score 0):

Setting a stop loss limit is a good policy. Two reasons:

- you might be otherwise occupied when a fall occurs (vacation, whatever)
- you might not be 100% rational when seeing your investment evaporate (see Kahneman & Tversky) and it is good idea to set your limits for cutting losses ahead, in cool mind and not in an adrenaline rush.